# JAXB package-info.java declarations are ignored in separate maven modul

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb, package-info

I use `package-info.java` to specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` and some xml java adapters using `@XmlJavaTypeAdapters`. Model objects (with JAXB annotations) are placed in separate maven module shared by other modules. The configuration in `package-info.java` is not discovered if model objects are in separate maven module. If I move for testing purposes model objects to same maven module everything is OK. I think separate maven module can be considered equivalent to 3rd party lib from `JAXBContext` point of view. I use JDK1.7 JAXB reference implementation. Any ideas how configuration may differ?

Comment: Where is the package-info.java located?

Comment: package-info.java is located in the same package as my model objects.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem, in my case qualified/unqualified property from package-info.java was ignored. I managed to find two way to workaround this:

- like Pavla wrote, copy all JAXB classes with package-info.java locally
- include module as a dependency with compile scope (which gives similar result that classes are in module. In my case I created separate jar lib with JAXB classes)

I also spotted that it do not work only in case of creating WebServices (creating object and sending to WS works fine in different modules).

I am using Jbossas7.1.1 and cxf 2.4.6. In the time of registering service Jboss created wsdl from JAXB (in my case path /opt/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/wsdl/module.war/SubmitMessage.wsdl). In local setting file is generated properly.

Any ideas why creating WS behaves like this?

Comment: if you have another question, post it on another thread, dont post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue recently and the actual problem (with Java 8, i.e. no Java modules involved) was that I had on the classpath two *.jar files which both contained the same package - in one JAR, there was package-info.class with JAXB annotations and in the other one, there wasn't.
In that case, I guess that if package-info.class file is discovered depends on the classpath ordering (which is very brittle and only semi-deterministic).